# how does the regular expression work in python on interpret the pattern '\\\\mac\\\\'

Tags: python, regex

i can not figure out how does regular expression to interpret the pattern **`\\\\mac\\\\`**. It comes out in python that **`\\mac\\`**.

however, i wander why does not the re module in python to continually interpret the pattern to **`\mac\`** since it has double backslash both before and behind the word **`mac`** in **`\\mac\\`**.

Does it means that re do the escapes just for one time and will not escape the string that has been escaped. Does someone can help me?

Comment: Do you want to match `**\\\\mac\\\\**` or it is the regular expression itself ?

Comment: \ is a metacharacter so if you want to match that your pattern will have to add \ to escape \ so you will end up with \\.

Comment: `>>> re.match(r'\*\*\\\\mac\\\\\*\*', r'**\\mac\\**')
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x10a1718>` Try to improve you writing, it is very hard to understan what you need.

Comment: @Sniffer i mean `**\\\\mac\\\\**` is a regular expression.

Comment: @F.C. sorry for my terrible expression to mislead you. I have edit it, so can you please see it again and explain it.

Comment: Just to clarify, what you need is a regular expression that matches "\\mac\\" (two backslashes mac and two backslashes) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the regexp string literals (prefixed with `r`) for denoting such monsters:

```
r'\\\\mac\\\\'
```

Then all your characters stay the way they are given.

```
>>> print r'\\\\mac\\\\'
\\\\mac\\\\
```

If you want to get a regexp *matching* such a monster, you will need to escape each special character:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(, r'\\\\mac\\\\')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7febff89d850>
```

Quoting and escaping often run into hard to understand situations if more than one interpretation steps take place.  In this case the regexp function `match` interprets the string it is given (`\\\\\\\\mac\\\\\\\\`).  Since a backslash has a special meaning as escape character in the language of regexps, a *verbatim* backslash must be escaped (again with a backslash).  So each backslash is doubled.  That's why you need eight literal backslashes to represent four verbatim backslashes.  If you do not use the `r` notation as a prefix to the string literal, then you'd have to double each backslash because the string parser already interprets the backslashes in string literals without `r` prefix, i. e.:

```
r'\\\\\\\\mac\\\\\\\\' == '\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\mac\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'
```

And that's why I call those "monsters".

Comment: sorry for my terrible expression to mislead you. I have edit it, so can you please see it again and explain it.

Comment: Does my explanation help?  Otherwise please ask a more elaborate question on how to help you.